# add labels to points bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have the following based on their docs:

```
album_names = ['Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Z', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Z', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Ctrl', 'Z']
valence = [0.37, 0.598, 0.481, 0.166, 0.413, 0.0798, 0.549, 0.332, 0.348, 0.335, 0.355, 0.22, 0.433, 0.158, 0.357, 0.134, 0.367, 0.237, 0.248, 0.239, 0.535, 0.432, 0.505, 0.142]
energy = [0.579, 0.686, 0.551, 0.367, 0.61, 0.475, 0.488, 0.525, 0.534, 0.517, 0.56, 0.342, 0.688, 0.505, 0.551, 0.63, 0.71, 0.453, 0.518, 0.708, 0.463, 0.684, 0.296, 0.576]`

df = pd.DataFrame([album_names, energy, valence]).T
df.columns = ['album_name', 'energy', 'valence']
```

I want to make a scatter plot using bokeh with valence on the x axis, energy on the y axis. Also, when you hover over each point, I want it to say it's value for `album_name`. And the color of the point is based `album_name`.

I have tried the following:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d, LabelSet, Label
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import brewer

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(valence=valence,
                                    energy=energy,
                                    names=album_names))

p = figure()
p.scatter(x='valence', y='energy', size=8, source=source)
labels = LabelSet(x='valence', y='energy', text='names',
                  level='glyph', x_offset=5, y_offset=5,
                  source=source, render_mode='canvas')

p.add_layout(labels)
show(p)
```

But this does not show the album name as you hover over the point. It fixes the album name next to the point. Any help in getting the album_name to show only when hovering over the point and changing the color based on the value of album_name would be greatly appreciated

Note: it would like similar to below
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @user4261201. Had no idea how to format the code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this it will do the trick:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, WheelZoomTool, PanTool, BoxZoomTool, ResetTool, TapTool, SaveTool
from bokeh.palettes import brewer

output_notebook()

#preprocessing the data with column album_name
category = 'album_name'

category_items = df[category].unique()
#selecting the colors for each unique category in album_name
palette = brewer['Set2'][len(category_items) + 1]
#mapping each category with a color of Set2
colormap = dict(zip(category_items, palette))
#making a color column based on album_name
df['color'] = df[category].map(colormap)

title = "Album_names"
#feeding data into ColumnDataSource
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
#Editing the hover that need to displayed while hovering
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Album_name', '@album_name')])
#tools that are need to explote data
tools = [hover, WheelZoomTool(), PanTool(), BoxZoomTool(), ResetTool(), SaveTool()]

#finally making figure with scatter plot
p = figure(tools=tools,title=title,plot_width=700,plot_height=400,toolbar_location='right',toolbar_sticky=False, )
p.scatter(x='valence',y='energy',source=source,size=10,color='color',legend=category)

#displaying the graph
show(p)
```

The output will be displayed as shown for album_name Ctrl[image: Ctrl]
The output will be displayed as shown for album_name Z[image: Z]

Comment: Looks great! I assume that `brewer['Set2'][len(category_items) + 1]` is because brewer['Set2'] has a min of three options?

Comment: @iwtbid it is to chose colors which you want to display in the graph. If it helped feel free to accept/upvote the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

album_names = [...]
valence = [...]
energy = [...]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(valence=valence,
                                    energy=energy,
                                    names=album_names))

p = figure(tools=[HoverTool(tooltips=[('Album Name', '@names'),
                                      ('Valence', '@valence'),
                                      ('Energy', '@energy')])])
p.scatter(x='valence', y='energy', size=8, source=source)
show(p)
```

All tooltips are shown by the `HoverTool`, so you have to add it and configure it to show what you want.
You can find more details in its [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool).

Comment: If you use that documentation example directly you will not get the different colors for `album_names`. Check my solution which gives different color. @Eugene

Comment: Yeah, the title of the question doesn't include coloring the points, so I overlooked it.